# Error when trying to start Slate: WebpackOptionsValidationError

Tags: npm, shopify, slate

Recently I've set up Slate using [these steps](https://shopify.github.io/slate/docs/create-a-new-slate-project) to work on my Shopify themes locally. It worked fine, but after a while i got an error when attempting to `npm start` Slate in the terminal.

I've tried updating npm and node and they are both the latest version.

This is the error I get in the terminal:

```
starter-theme@1.0.0-alpha.1 start path-to-project 
slate-tools start

WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
         - configuration.entry should be an non-empty object.    
-> Multiple entry bundles are created. The key is the chunk name. The value can be a string or an array.
            at webpack (path-to-project-folder/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:31:9)
            at new DevServer (path-to-project-folder/node_modules/@shopify/slate-tools/tools/asset-server/index.js:21:21)
            at path-to-project-folder/node_modules/@shopify/slate-tools/cli/commands/start.js:48:19 
        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
        npm ERR! errno 1 
        npm ERR! starter-theme@1.0.0-alpha.1 start: `slate-tools start` 
        npm ERR! Exit status 1 
        npm ERR!  
        npm ERR! Failed at the starter-theme@1.0.0-alpha.1 start script. 
        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

This is the slate.config.js file:

```
    /* eslint-disable */

// Configuration file for all things Slate.
// For more information, visit https://github.com/Shopify/slate/wiki/Slate-Configuration

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

  'cssVarLoader.liquidPath': ['src/snippets/css-variables.liquid'],
  'webpack.extend': {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        jquery: path.resolve('./node_modules/jquery'),
        'lodash-es': path.resolve('./node_modules/lodash-es'),
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Has anyone run into this issue before, how did you fix it?

Comment: Have you tryed to completely remove node_modules directory and execute a new npm install ?